# Responsive webpage with all contents adjusting itself within the height and width of browser?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, html, responsive

My requirements for the webpage is the contents for the webpage should be able to view across platforms and devices(mainly, different screen resolutions). Also there should be NO SCROLL BARS(i.e.) all the contents should be contained within the browsers viewport.

Is it possible with bootstrap or any other Frameworks?

Note: No scroll bar should appear(contents should adjust width-wise and height-wise. So that everything just fits is inside the page WITHOUT any scroll)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.`Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.`-From their website.

Answer (score 0):

**Example of Responsive webpage**

Try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Responsive Bootstrap Example</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  </div>

</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" id="txtName">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input id="txtName" type="text" class="form-control input-number" placeholder="Name" maxlength="10" />
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" id="txtEmailId">Email ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input id="txtEmailId" type="text" class="form-control input-number" placeholder="Email ID" maxlength="10" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Remarks</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
            <textarea id="txtRemarks" class="form-control resizenone" rows="3" maxlength="250" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divConfBtn" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-3">
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the above page creates scroll bar in different resolutions as well as in iphone device mode in chrome. In my question, I mentioned that the page should not create scroll bar and all contents should be visible.